# Words used for worst performance by artists

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Can we say excruciatingly painful performance by the singer. Or there any other words , phrases that could be used instead?

Comment: Yes, that gets the message across...

Comment: Awfully bad, terribly bad,  very lousy.

Comment: "Excruciatingly painful" would be understood as hyperbole. But it would probably just be "excruciating".

Comment: You can go to a thesaurus and look up synonyms for "bad" and then use Google to see which of them tend to be used in reviews of musical performances. Your question is too open-ended.

Comment: Lots of performing artists, and particularly comedians, use the verb *bombed*.

Comment: Off-key musical performances often hurt to listen to.

Answer (score 1):

*Bombed* is a good all-purpose word, as Dan mentions.  Other common phrases are *blew it*, *stunk it up* (slang, because the correct grammar would be *stank*) and sometimes *loused it up* or *crumbed it up*.  A couple of more colorful ones are *laid an egg* and *crashed and burned*. *Messed up* and *fouled up* are a bit gentler, while *flopped* and *fell flat* are more  polite terms.

Of these, a performance can bomb, stink, flop or fall flat, and so can an artist.  Only the artist can blow it, or louse, crumb, mess or foul up (a performance).  While it's possible for a performance to lay an egg or crash and burn, it's much more common for the artist(s) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase you used works.  You could also talk about wanting to throw rotten tomatoes, as they did for the premiere of Stravinsky's wonderful ballet, Rite of Spring.